# How to get the post title where the post content length less than 300 words in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

how can i get the post titles list where post content less than 300 words ..

1) posts title(List of posts) where post content less than 300 words in wordpress

2) posts title(List of posts) where post content less than 300-500 words in wordpress

is there any plugin or filter function for this requirement.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is, no.

If your site doesn't include a huge number of posts, you could just use WP_Query and check all posts with some PHP code, e.g.

```
$all_posts = new WP_Query( array(
    "post_type" => "post",
    "posts_per_page" => 10000,
    "post_status" => "any"
) );
while($all_posts->have_posts()) {
    $all_posts->the_post();
    if(str_word_count($post->post_content, 0) < 300) {
        print $post->post_title . "<br />\n";
    }
}
```